# Why I am getting "getuid was not declared in that scope" error?

Tags: c++, getpwuid

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pwd.h>

std::string impPath()
{
    char *name;
    struct passwd *pass;
    pass = getpwuid(getuid());
    name = pass->pw_name;

    std::string PATH = "/home";
    PATH.append("/");
    PATH.append(name);

    return PATH;
}
```

I need to know *username* of the user. In order to do this. I am using `getpwuid()` but I am getting this error.

```
/home/shobhit/Desktop/file.cpp:15: error: 'getuid' was not declared in this scope
 pass = getpwuid(getuid());
                        ^
```

I just couldn't figure out what is the reason that *getuid* is not declared in this scope. I think I have included all the necessary header files.(yami's comment on R's answer [getlogin() c function returns NULL and error "No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785126/getlogin-c-function-returns-null-and-error-no-such-file-or-directory)
I have tried searching on the web but couldn't find any relevant answer.

Comment: Did you try `man getuid`?

Comment: Also C and C++ are not Java. You do not "*include libraries*", but header files, which in fact are source code. *If* libraries are used, then they are *linked*, this is done later, *after compilation* of the source code is done.

Comment: Yeah thanx I have edited my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`man getuid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html):

> #### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
> #include <sys/types.h>
>
> uid_t getuid(void);
> uid_t geteuid(void);
> ```

You're missing those includes.

Comment: what is the meaning of these lines 
uid_t getuid(void);
uid_t geteuid(void);

Comment: @shobhit They're function declarations. It's how manual pages show you the type and name of an entity. It means "by including these headers, you get access to `getuid` (a function taking no arguments and returning a `uid_t`) and `geteuid` (a function taking no arguments and returning a `uid_t`)."

Comment: @shobhit Yes, that's what this documentation shows you.

Comment: @shobhit I don't think it was a good question. Your code sample is neither complete (what is `"impfile_path.h"`?) nor minimal (all of the `std::string` and `getpwuid` stuff is irrelevant). You claim "*I have included all the necessary header files*" without justification (and is it turns out, your claim is wrong). The question shows no research effort (why do you think you've included all the necessary headers? how did you determine the required headers?). I think it's unlikely to be helpful for others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173290/discussion-between-shobhit-and-melpomene).

Answer (score 1):

`getuid()` is not present in `pwd.h`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pwd.h.html