# Why do these two methods work to solve the "implicit declaration of function"?

Tags: c

I am new to C, and I encounter a very confusing phenomenon.
Here is the code snippet:

```c
// hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Hello, %s!\n", getlogin());
}
```

When I use `cc hello.c` to compile it, I'll get a warning message and the run `./a.out` will cause a segment fault.

Just like this:

```sh
client@ubuntu:01$ cc hello.c 
hello.c: In function ‘main’:
hello.c:5:26: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getlogin’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    5 |  printf("Hello,  %s!\n", getlogin());
      |                          ^~~~~~~~
hello.c:5:19: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
    5 |  printf("Hello,  %s!\n", getlogin());
      |                  ~^      ~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   |      |
      |                   char * int
      |                  %d
client@ubuntu:01$ ./a.out 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But these two methods will work to solve this problem:
Here is the first method

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Hello, %s!\n", getlogin());
}
```

And here is the second method:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char * getlogin();

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Hello, %s!\n", getlogin());
}
```

I can understand the first solution, but why does the second solution can work?
Thank you, my friend.

Comment: The root of your problem is that you are using an old, outdated C90 compiler. I recommend switching to a newer version of gcc, then compile like this: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Comment: What do you think is the difference between both solutions wrt `getlogin`? Both are exactly the same. They provide the missing declaration your compiler complained about. It does not matter if you put that declaration in the same file or include another file that contains the same declaration. (Let's ignore the missing `void` for the moment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the second solution, the object file will compile, because the declaration of the function was provided, and the call to that function is compatible with that declaration.

Most compilers by default will link programs against the standard C library on that platform. The linker will find the `getlogin` symbol in that library and use that. Therefore the linker is also satisfied.

The following program works (and does nothing):

```
char *getlogin(void);

int main(void)
{
    (void) getlogin();
}
```

Now when you compile it with normal parameters, it will most likely just work.

However, if you pass `-nostdlib` or use whatever method your compiler might use to avoid linking to the standard library, it does *not* work, and the linker should complain. For example:

```
undefined reference to `getlogin'
```

Comment: The program is unlikely to actually run, because `-nostdlib` disrupts a bit more than desired. But the general idea should be clear here.

Comment: `char * getlogin();` is a declaration. It is not a definition.

Comment: Thank you, I am confused by the structure of C language. But how can the compiler find where the `getlogin()` is? I mean since I just provide the prototype of the `getlogin()`, how the compiler know the source code of that function?

Comment: The compiler does not know. The linker tries to find a symbol by that name, and the linker does not know about the function declaration.

Answer (score 2):

C is now a rather old language: it was created in the 70' as a tool to build Unix kernels. Even though it has evolved a lot, it still has at some place the good old *you are the boss, and I shall obey* rule. Function declaration is one of this places:

- external functions (which will be resolved at link time) have to be *declared* in the compilation unit, and have to be provided to the linker. Both operations are completely independent (which often leads to crashes if the linked function and the declared one are not the same...)
- if a function is used without being declared, it is just supposed to return an `int` value and give no indication on the expected parameter (here the missing declaration is taken as `int getlogin()`).

The underlying rationale, is that it allows *lazy* programmers to skip function declarations if they are sure to always pass the correct parameters.

That was for the context, next here is the answer to your question: include files of the standard library are nothing more than a collection of declarations. And as the `#include` directive only includes the text of the external file, *including* a header in a compilation unit, or manually typing the declaration are strictly equivalent on a compiler point of view.

---

It does not mean that you can do either way. Including header files is a guarantee that you will consistently use the correct declaration, while manually adding the declaration in all the compilation unit adds a great risk for typos, and will make maintenance harder because the declaration are scattered among plenty of files instead of being cleanly and nicely in one single place.

Comment: I don't think there's any underlying rationale at all. Back in the days when dinosaurs walked the earth, C didn't have any other type than `int`. So "implicit int" was not a big deal. With the introduction of other types and ISO standardization, "implicit int" became a big problem and a language flaw - which was later fixed in the C99 version of the language.

Comment: @Lundin: I did use K&R C in the 80' before the first ISO version and it did already have the standard types. The implicit int was not a big deal for pointers which were cleanly convertible to int, but was for `float` and `double` type. That being said, I agree with you, there is probably not rationale at all but it is the way the language was invented...

Comment: Yes I'm talking about far earlier, K&R 1st edition and 1970s. From what I can tell some "de facto" standard evolved during the 1980s.

Comment: @Lundin: Was too young for 1st edition...

Comment: Thank you very much, I am confused by the structure of C language. But how can the compiler find where the getlogin() is? I mean since I just provide the prototype of the getlogin(), how the compiler know the source code of that function?

Comment: The *compiler* doest not know. But later the linker uses the *standard library* to resolve the still undefined symbols.

Comment: @Lundin: C never “didn’t have any other type than `int`.” In K&R first edition, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `unsigned`, `float`, and `double` are present, as well as `struct` and `union` (no `enum` or `long long`). B and BCPL were word/cell-based. [Per Ritchie’s C history](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html), “In 1971 I began to extend the B language by adding a character type… I called the slightly-extended language NB, for ‘new B’.” Then he added structures. “After creating the type system, the associated syntax… I felt that it deserved a new name… called it C…”

Answer (score 0):

**Declaration** is giving information about variable type or function to the **compile**r; in your case giving information about function return type and its arguments to the compiler.

Before using any standard functions we must have to check with their **declarations** (must be same as declared in header files) to avoid such warnings, else we are required to include header files which contains those declarations.

And `getlogin()` is not recommended to use
[getlogin() c function returns NULL and error "No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785126/getlogin-c-function-returns-null-and-error-no-such-file-or-directory)